# svnserver repository prompts the revision file lacks tracking newline

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

The server hard disk is broken (the backup folder of svn cannot be found), and the repository needs to be restored. However, the repository always prompts " the revision file lacks tracking newline". If the import method is used to restore, it will prompt “can't open file 'D:/repository/XX/db/revs/xx/xxxx'”，I don't have more files ,how can i fix it.

I  tried Remove the revision file in revs and revprops ，but some sub folders prompts errors(lack vision file)
I also tried to use different versions of svnserver ,but still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Corrupt repository in your case means data loss. Most likely you will be unable to recover the repository with all its version history without a backup. The best approach to solve this problem is to restore a backup.

To confirm that the repository is corrupt, you can run the [Test-SvnRepository](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Test-SvnRepository) PowerShell cmdlet or run the [repository verification job](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00115/).

And find working copies checked out from this repository. Although they won't help you restore the history of changes of this corrupt repository, they will help you create a new repository with the latest snapshot of the data from the corrupt one.